# What's contained in PHP rowset on insert

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I'm inserting data into a SQL Srv stored procedure using PHP PDO.
I want the number of rows affected, the return value and an output value.
Note all of this works

Heres my connection

```
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=$hostname;Database=$dbname", "$username", "$pw");
            echo "Connection established.<br />";
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);;
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING, PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_SYSTEM);
```

Here's the rest

```
 $sql = "EXEC ? = the_stored_procedure ?, ?";
            $sth = $conn->prepare($sql);
$retval = 99;
            $bite = '999';

            $sth->bindParam(1, $retval, PDO::PARAM_INT | PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, PDO::SQLSRV_PARAM_OUT_DEFAULT_SIZE);
            $sth->bindParam(2, $bite);
            $sth->bindParam(3, $responseMessage, PDO::PARAM_STR | PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 512);
$sth->execute();
```

As I said this all works but to get the information I'm using

```
echo "rowcount: " . $sth->rowCount() . "<br>";
$sth->nextRowset();
$sth->nextRowset();
echo "RETURN: " . $retval . "<br>";
echo "OUTPUT: " . $responseMessage . "<br>";
```

So the question is why do I need 2 x nextRowset() and what's contained in them?

Note:
If I changed the EXEC line to:

```
$sql = "SET NOCOUNT ON; EXEC ? = ComC_i_Survey_Start_php ?, ?";
```

There would be no rowcount but I can simply call

```
echo "<br>RETURN:" . $retval . "<br>";
echo "<br>OUTPUT:" . $responseMessage . "<br>";
```

without the need for

$sth->nextRowset();

Comment: Because you need to process results before getting output params and nocount off generates resultsets. So set nocount on is a way of skipping these resultsets and go straight to the params

Comment: @siggemannen - I sort of worked that out but if i wanted the rowcount I would have to run 2 x $sth->nextRowset(); to get to the return value and output. 

I'm not expecting any results so these are probably empty rowsets - the question I guess is why they are there

Comment: because affected row counts are communicated back in form of resultsets. say you have in your procedure, `insert into sometable select 1, 2, 3` that would generate a rowcount resultset. If you want both cake and eat it, i would suggest adding another parameter that gathers rowcounts you need and then outputs it explicitely instead of relying on php dito, something like: `insert into sometable select 1, 2, 3; set @rowcountOutput = @@ROWCOUNT`

Comment: I understand that insert will generate a rowcount resultset and it's the first thing. How do we find out whats in the other resultsets (without a fetch - which causes an error) or are they empty